# Django Providing initial data for models with model triggers

Tags: django, populate, django-fixtures

I have a Django 1.6.2 application, some of model logics (overrided "save" methods and signal event handlers), and I use the `loaddata fixture\data.json` command to populate the initial database.

But, problem is - loaddata doesn't triggering the `save` methods and doesn't sent the `signal`. It's just dump data's to base...

Can you suggest the fixture- or populate-method for initialaze the base with data + all models logic?

Comment: Why would you need to run the triggers? The point of db fixtures is that they contain fully ready data.

Comment: Because I want to test the triggers, and because I have a lot of test data, devided on 2 part each: user data and system generated cache

Answer (score 1):

I found an example of population script, it covering my needs

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models.html#creating-a-population-script